# Send list of values as a parameter

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soapui

I use `SoapUi` to test my web service. I want to sent from SoapUi a list of parameter for a `post` method.  Here is the code where I want to handle the list but is not working, I get a `null pointer exception` :

```
   @POST
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Path("/subscribeList")
   public Response subscribe( final MultivaluedMap<String, String> listoffields )
   {
      System.out.println( "The list has: " + listoffields.size() );
      return Response.ok().build();
   }
```

From `soapui` I send the parameters as `queryparam`. 
Can anyone help me solve this problem and be able to send a list?

Comment: What's your input - the body of your message?

Comment: I just make this request from `soapui`: `http://localhost:8888:/service/subscription/subscribeList?name=name5&age=age5`

Comment: DO you mean to say that, you need name and age as part of MultivaluedMap<String, String> listoffields ?

Comment: I just want to pass field `name` and `age` as a list, not separated values. I have also tried with `FormParam` but I get `unknown media type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject [`UriInfo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html) as the method parameter, and get the map with `UriInfo.getQueryParameters()`.

```
public Response subscribe( @Context UriInfo uriInfo ) {
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();
    String name = queryParams.getFirst("name");
}
```

Or you can explicitly specify the each query param in the method signature

```
public Response subscribe( @QueryParam("name") String name,
                           @QueryParam("age") int age ) {
```